# Background image not loading in chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have this:

```
 <style type="text/css">
.blackitout {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background: #000 url('/images/loading.gif') no-repeat center;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index:99;
}
</style>
<script>
function testfunction (){
    $('#mytest').addClass('blackitout');
}
</script>
```

I have a link that onclick calls my testfunction. which adds the above class to an empty div.  This gives me a dimmed page and a loading gif. Which works in firefox. But not chrome.  In chrome, if I manually load the image on a blank page, and then either add or remove the quotes on around the link in my css and save. It will start working for a bit.  Maybe I just need a better way to do it than an empty div class and adding the class(which is then removed when the next page loads).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
.blackitout {
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    background-color: #000;
    background-image: url('/images/loading.gif') ;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    opacity: 0.7;
    z-index:99;
}
```

Comment: Same result. Fine in firefox. Not working in chrome.  I think I had it like that originally, and then changed it to a one liner when I found the problem.